# Does MOUSE_WHEEL have a min delta value before it fires?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I am having some trouble with MOUSE_WHEEL delta values.  It seems like the event doesn't fire unless I REALLY spin the dammed wheel.  Which makes sense because the only values I get range from 3-30. I was hoping to catch 1-3 as well because if I just spin a few notches, nothing triggers and the app feels sluggish.

FYI every other program on my machine feels those 1-notch spins just fine so it's not the mouse.  Will AS3 not fire if the delta is less than 3?

Here is the code

```
private function handleMouseWheel(e:MouseEvent):void {
trace(e.delta); 
    // Output is always more/less than +/- 3 
}

private function handleStageInit(e:Event):void {
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, handleMouseWheel);
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  I have multiple mice.  I can use one, and flash picks up the scroll event just fine (it always shows a delta of +/- 3 or greater.  One of my mice produces a smaller delta when scrolled, and the event is never fired.  This is a problem in both the debug tool, and in browsers.

Comment: What context does your application run in?   Web? Mobile? Desktop?

Answer (score 5):

AS3 doesn't have any customizable value for wheel sensitivity.

The way it works, I believe, is dependent on BOTH the **physical mouse**, and the **OS settings**.

For instance, in *windows* you set the sensitivity of various mouse settings in *ControlPanel -> Mouse.*
In the Wheel tab, the user can set how many lines (eg. delta) the wheel does for each physical notch.  The default is 3.

At the same time, each physical mouse has different notch sensitivity, eg. how much you need to move it to register a 'notch' in the OS.

I believe the swf's container also has some influence as well,  so it may behave differently in different browsers, and as a projector, and in your IDE.

For browsers, most people seem to bypass flash and listen/pass the JavaScript scroll wheel events into flash:

See these libraries:

https://github.com/digi604/As3-Mouse-Wheel-Fixer

http://labs.byhook.com/2010/04/09/flash-mouse-wheel-support/

Comment: @Jason - This might be a good read:  http://labs.byhook.com/2010/04/09/flash-mouse-wheel-support/

Comment: @Boundless - I agree this is a huge annoyance in flash that I've run into in the past and it's dumb that to make it work decently you have to use JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

[According to ilike2Flash](http://www.ilike2flash.com/2009/07/mousewheel-in-actionscript-3.html) the change in the delta may be dependent on the user's mouse.

Comment: Then why do other programs notice?  I understand that the actual value of the delta can change from user to user (its an OS setting).  But,talking about the physical mouse,I can scroll on notch in any other program (chrome included) and it registers.  But AS3 only seems to notice if I REALLY spin the wheel; values aside, the event doesn't even TRIGGER unless I REALLY spin the damn wheel.

Comment: I don't know. The [documentation for MouseEvent.delta](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#delta) says "Typical values are 1 to 3, but faster rotation may produce larger values. This setting depends on the device and operating system and is usually configurable by the user."  There's not any JavaScript on the same page that could be intercepting mouse wheel events is there?

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in your code or device, please take a look at [this](http://blog.flexexamples.com/wp-content/uploads/MouseWheel_test/bin/main.html) sample(you can right click to view the code). It works just fine on my machine.

Comment: And what range of delta do you see when you scroll?

Comment: So if you scroll up slowly, up fast, down slowly, or down fast you only get a delta of 1?  It seems like you have a problem on your end.

Comment: @Boundless no, when I scroll fast I get 1-3 deltas, and when I scroll slaw so only one. Man it works just fine for me really, try it on other devices too

Answer (score -2):

AS3 fire only +3 (up scroll) and -3 (down scroll), but we can calculate our requirements by dividing some constant.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, mouseWheelHandler);

function mouseWheelHandler(ev){
    trace(ev.delta/3); // +1 or -1
    trace(ev.delta/6); // +.5 or -.5
}
```

Comment: That doesn't even make any sense. -1

Comment: The problem is, in debug the event handler doesn't get fired for a delta less than +/- 3.  In the browser a delta of less than +/- 3 is converted to 0.